# Invoking Local API from a Laravel controller within the same Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel 10 and have created an API using Laravel Sanctum. I want this local API to display a view in my controller. The API functions correctly when tested with Postman, but when it's called in my controller, the page fails to load and eventually times out. I have already set my memory limit in `php.ini` to 512M, and I'm using PHP 8.1.27. Do you know how I can call the API locally with Sanctum?

**module/api/routes/api.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'api']], function () {
    Route::get('sample', [ApiController::class, 'sample']);
});
```

**Controller**

```
  $response = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::withHeaders([
    "Accept"=> "application/json",
    "Authorization" => "Bearer " . env('SANCTUM_AUTH')
])
->get(route('sample').'/', ['type' => '2']);
  dd($response);
```

**Error**

> cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30006 milliseconds with 0
> bytes received (see
> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample/?type=2

Comment: by invoking locally, do you mean you're trying to call an API route from within the same Laravel application?

if you're trying to call an API route from within the same Laravel application, this is not a good practice, as making  an HTTP request to your application can lead to issues like timeouts.  based on the sample shown ,it seems to me that you are  creating a recursive call, leading to a timeout

Comment: yes, an API call within the same application. I was thinking i'd do so, to use my own API and make it easier to display since the data output is already formatted. I've done before on a previous project using Yii and worked tho :(